# IronWorker, CasperJS and cookies support

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs, ironworker

I got everything working with Ironworker and casperjs and I have one more step which fails: enabling cookie support in this setup.

I'm starting casper with the `--cookies-file=cookies.txt` param and the cookies.txt file is chmoded with the right permissions but somehow there's no cookie support when I visit a test page and screenshot it.

Any idea how to enable this feature with IronWorker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [casperjs](https://github.com/iron-io/iron_worker_examples/tree/master/binary/casperjs) example but without phantomjs (it is already included in phantom-1.9 stack)

casper.worker:

```
runtime "binary"
stack "phantom-1.9"
exec "run.sh"

# Include the CasperJS library
dir "casperjs"

# Include the Javascript file that Casper will execute
file "simple.js"
```

run.sh:

```
casperjs/bin/casperjs --verbose --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --ssl-protocol=any --cookies-file=cookies.txt simple.js
```

simple.js:

```js
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i586; rv:31.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36')

casper.start('https://hud.iron.io/', function() {
    this.fill('form[action="/sessions"]', { email: 'foo@bar.com', password: 'super_hard_pass' }, true);
    this.click('input[name="commit"]');
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.wait('10000');

casper.thenOpen('https://hud.iron.io/account', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
    this.echo(this.evaluate(function() {return document.querySelector(".account-header").innerText}));
});

casper.run();
```